# Understanding change-of-basis and linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

First of all , apologies in advance as this isn't so much as a question, but more check of my understanding.

Suppose I have an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ and a given basis $\mathfrak{B}= \lbrace\mathbf{e}_{i}\rbrace$, such that each $\mathbf{v}\in V$ can be expressed as a *unique* linear combination of these basis vectors, i.e. $$\mathbf{v} = \sum_{i} a^{i}\mathbf{e}_{i}$$
Now, suppose that I have some linear operator $\mathcal{T} \in \mathcal{L}\left(V,V\right)$ (i.e. $\mathcal{T}:V\rightarrow V$) defined in such a way that it maps the $j^{th}$ basis vector $\mathbf{e}_{j}\in \mathfrak{B}$ to the $j^{th}$ vector $\mathbf{e}'_{j}$ in some other basis $\mathfrak{B}'$ for $V$, i.e. $$\mathcal{T}\left(\mathbf{e}_{j}\right)= \mathbf{e}'_{j}$$
To guarantee that the set of vectors that $\mathcal{T}$ maps to is linearly independent, we require that it is an injective map which further implies that it is surjective. This means that the set $\mathfrak{B}'$ is linearly independent and spans $V$, therefore fulfilling the requirements of a basis for $V$.

As $\mathcal{T}:V\rightarrow V$ we therefore know that $\mathcal{T}\left(\mathbf{e}_{j}\right)= \mathbf{e}'_{j}\in V$ and thus it can be expressed as a *unique* linear combination of the basis vectors in $\mathfrak{B}$, $$\mathbf{e}'_{j} = \sum_{i}\left(\mathbf{e}'_{j}\right)^{i}\mathbf{e}_{i} =  \sum_{i}\left(\mathcal{T}\left(\mathbf{e}_{j}\right)\right)^{i}\mathbf{e}_{i}$$
Where $\left(\mathbf{e}'_{j}\right)^{i} = \left(\mathcal{T}\left(\mathbf{e}_{j}\right)\right)^{i}$ is the $i^{th}$ component of the new basis vector $\mathbf{e}'_{j} \in \mathfrak{B}'$ with respect to the old basis $\mathfrak{B}$. As we know that a given vector can be represented as a column vector with respect to a given basis, where the row elements are given by the components of the vector with respect to that basis, this implies that $$\left(\mathcal{T}\left(\mathbf{e}_{j}\right)\right)^{i} = \mathcal{T}^{i}_{\,\,\,\,j}$$
and hence, $$\mathbf{e}'_{j}= \sum_{i}\mathcal{T}^{i}_{\,\,\,\,j}\mathbf{e}_{i}$$

Now, as a given vector $\mathbf{v}\in V$ exists independently of any basis its representations with respect to two different bases should be equivalent. As such, $$\mathbf{v}= \sum_{i} a^{i}\mathbf{e}_{i} = \sum_{j} (a')^{j}\mathbf{e'}_{j} = \sum_{j} (a')^{j}\left(\sum_{i}\mathcal{T}^{i}_{\,\,\,\,j}\mathbf{e}_{i}\right)= \sum_{i}\left(\sum_{j} \mathcal{T}^{i}_{\,\,\,\,j}(a')^{j}\right)\mathbf{e}_{i}$$
implying that the components of $\mathbf{v}$ with respect to the two bases $\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathfrak{B}'$ are related by $$a^{i}= \sum_{j} \mathcal{T}^{i}_{\,\,\,\,j}(a')^{j}$$

Sorry for the long-windedness of this post, but is what I've written along the right lines?